# Exchanging a Motorhome (RV) between USA and Australia

Tags: usa, australia, motor-homes

We are planning to visit USA in October and November 2014 and would like to arrange a swap for the Motorhome we have in Australia for one in USA.  Does anyone have any contacts we might try.  We would also be interested to hear any experiences others may have had.

Comment: Getting an insurance for it might be the tricky part if you don't rent it from an agency...

Answer (score 4):

You're not the first to wonder, and there are already websites set up for such plans!

[RVWorldWide](http://www.rvworldwide.com/listing/guide/exchangeswap_my_rv) has an exchange/swap program, and indeed there are Aussie and American listings on there.  It would be worth a post.

[MotorhomeHolidaySwap](http://www.motorhomeholidayswap.com/) is growing, it only has 1700 members, but these are actively trying to swap for holidays around the world, so does sound exactly like what you're looking for.